# Unable to access specific rest apis due to azure error

Tags: azure, entra-id, azure-networking, azure-web-apps, entra-domain-services

My application using spring rest and deployed in Azure server. Created rest apis using spring rest.

Am able to access all rest urls, except in one scenario.

for eg:  `http://mydomain123.com/api/abc` , `http://mydomain123.com/api/xyz/abc`

Am able to access above urls

`http://mydomain123.com/api/bin` , `http://mydomain123.com/api/xyz/bin` , `http://mydomain123.com/api/bin/dfdff`

But above urls having bin word with which am getting below error:

```
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
```

I am trying as below,but not working at all:

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Please someone help me out to fix above issue (I should be able to access rest apis even having word "bin" in it)

Comment: any solution for above issue?

Comment: no one knows above ?

Comment: am waiting for some response.

Comment: Try testing them with powershell `Invoke-Restmethod`

Comment: This might be relevant also: https://www.koskila.net/how-to-fix-an-azure-function-v2-failing-with-error-the-resource-you-are-looking-for-has-been-removed-had-its-name-changed-or-is-temporarily-unavailable/